# Classic ASP Microsoft.XMLHTTP onreadystatechange

Tags: asynchronous, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make an async call with a callback function in classic ASP. This is my code:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
With objHTTP
    .open "POST", base_url_crm & "contacts", True, login_crm, key_crm
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    .onreadystatechange = Check_state
    .send json
End with

Set objHTTP = Nothing

Public Function Check_state
    if objHTTP.ReadyState = 4 then
        Response.Write "Finish"
    end if
End Function
```

Its return this error:

```
Type mismatch: 'onreadystatechange'
```

How can I execute the Check_state function right after the async call ends?
It must be async (dont wanna make my users wait) and cant do this in javascript.

Comment: You can't use an async call like this (even if you got the callback assigned correctly).  There's nothing to keep the  server-side script waiting for the callback: as soon as the `send` part is done the page will exit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind events to functions like you do in JavaScript because simply passing the name of the function will call it immediately, return its output, and that'll be assigned instead. Use the `GetRef` function to bind events like so:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
objHTTP.onreadystatechange = GetRef("Check_state")
```

[See here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ekabbe10(v=vs.84).aspx) for documentation on `GetRef`.

Comment: I am geting the "Invalid procedure call" error with GetRef.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the status instead of onreadystatechange , it returns values ​​such as 200, 404 and 500.

Comment: It wont be async if I have to code a loop to verify the status.